# Total Entropy of the Atkinson Cycle

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I was researching for a question that asked me to find a ratio of temperatures, and I came across this, which would help me greatly:

Since, most of the temperature changes occur during the isochoric (2–3) and isobaric processes (4–1), a constant specific heat can be assumed during the isentropic processes (1–2 and 3–4).
The total entropy change in the cycle must be equal to zero, therefore

$T_2T_4^k=T_3T_1^k$

where k is the rerversible adiabatic index.

But, I don't understand why due tho these factors this equation is true. Is there any clarification as to why this is the case?

Comment: For readers - see [Atkinson cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atkinson_cycle)

Comment: @Poutnik Apologies, was not aware, I have now edited the question

Comment: Let’s see your analysis so far.